# Rails 3.1: Custom validation message on join table of has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many-through

I have a `Meal` model that `has_many :foods, :through => :servings`. `Meal` also:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :servings, :allow_destroy => true
validates_associated :servings
```

The `Serving` model has a field called `serving_amount` and a field called `amount_recorded`. In the `Serving` model, I currently use this validation:

```
validates :serving_size, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}, :if => :amount_recorded?
```

The message returned if the validation fails is terrible. This is compounded by the fact that each meal may have multiple servings.

How do I create a custom validation message that refers to the name of the food for which the serving size is invalid? For example, I would like it to say, "You entered an invalid serving size for Watermelon," if `amount_recorded` is true for a serving of a `Food` with `name` watermelon and the validation fails.

Answer (score 3):

I would try the `validates_each` method. When calling the method, you pass it a block that will be passed the record instance (from the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_each)):

```
validates_each :first_name, :last_name do |record, attr, value|
  record.errors.add attr, 'starts with z.' if value.to_s[0] == zz
end
```

That means you can access any of the records attributes, including the name, and easily construct the error message.