# ActiveRecord validate :uniqueness on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I need to perform the validation to make sure that only one user within a company can exist within a given category.

```
  validates  :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:category, :company_id], :message => "already exists"}
```

This works except the error message is set on `:user_id` key.

How can I do the same but set the error on the `:user` key (`validates :user` gives an error)?

Comment: `validates :user, :uniqueness => { ... }` ?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479113/rails-3-1-custom-validation-message-on-join-table-of-has-many-through-relations/8479323#8479323

Comment: @Martin I have mentioned in the question that it raises the error.     The suggested duplicate is a totally different question.

Comment: sorry, the question is indeed totally different, I should have mentioned that a possible solution is in the answer to that question.

Comment: I think it will be fixed soon :) https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4321

Comment: @nash yep, that's exactly my case! I'll be watching that issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple way to check uniqueness and force the error to be assigned to the `:user` attribute:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :user_unique_per_company_per_category

  private

  def user_unique_per_company_per_category
    if self.class.exists?(:user_id => user_id, :company_id => company_id, :category => category)
      errors.add :user, 'already exists'
    end
  end
end
```

It would be preferable, I think, if you could figure out a way to use the default validation on `:user_id`, but maybe you have a special use case.

Also, if you're not using this in a form, you might consider assigning the error to `:base`, since you might confuse future developers who expect the error to appear on `:user_id`:

```
errors.add :base, 'already exists'
```

Comment: Yeah, custome validation so far is probably the best choice. I can't believe you can't apply this validation on user :( The problem with validating user_id is that it is never used on the UI, so the error message as you mentioned won't be in the proper place.

Comment: Does this work when you're editing a `User` record as well? The user you are saving would already be in the database but if you're updating that's okay.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible as the validates method of ActiveRecord *sends* the errors to the method being validated.

So validates :user trys to send to the attr_accessor of :user which doesn't exist in your model.

Though, if you're just trying to make the error message pretty you can:

```
alias user user_id
```

And then use :user in your validation.

```
validates  :user, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:category, :company_id], :message => "already exists"}
```

On a side note, I wouldn't use user in the alias rather something like:

```
alias the_supplied_user user_id
```

And then in your validation:

```
validates  :the_supplied_user, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:category, :company_id], :message => "already exists"}
```

Comment: Well, both user and user_id do exist as it's an association. So aliasing will just break everything.